# tCSS: Don't break line for tags

Tags: css

I have issues with how tags are showing up on posts on my website. I have a screenshot here displaying the issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7e2d.png

The top pos shows how it's supposed to look, with all tags within the borders. But as you see in the second one, the amount of tags breaks the design. I'd like it to  I'd like it to keep all tags on one row, not displaying the rest of the tags, or showing a "…" instead, so it can all fit within the borders.

```
#tags{
font-weight:normal;
font-size:11px; 
text-transform: lowercase;
font-family: "Goudy Old Style", Palatino, "Palatino Linotype", "Palatino LT STD", "Book Antiqua", Georgia, serif;color:{color:o main text};
padding-left:20px;
width:350px;
padding-bottom:5px;
}

#tags a{
color:{color:o main text};
}

#tags hover{
color:{color:white main text};
}
```

-

```
<divabc class="reblog_etc" style="text-transform: lowercase;font-size:10px;height:20px;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;float:left;background-image:url(http://static.tumblr.com/ssdtkch/OOHmg0ppe/middle.png);background-repeat:repeat-x;color:#FFF;opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=100);padding-top:2px;" >
{block:HasTags}
<span id="tags hover">
<span style="padding-left:13px; font-size:15px; color:{color:white}; font-family:'PictosRegular';">z </span>
<a href="/tags">tags</a> 
{block:Tags} <a style="color:{color:white}" href="{TagURL}">{Tag},</a> {/block:Tags}
</span></br>
<div style="height:5px; width:auto;"> </div>{/block:HasTags}</divabc>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this:

```
#tags{
   height:30px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

You will need to test the height, but that should work.